# UWP app Serialization of ObservableCollection and image

Tags: uwp

I use `ObservableCollection` and store `BitmapImage` there. Tried to serialize the `ObservableCollection` using Newtonsoft.Json, it only saves the text. Wanted to keep the image in the form of bytes, but have not found how to convert `BitmapImage` to `Byte[]`.

In general I have two questions:

1. Has the `ObservableCollection` of images to be serialized to a file?
2. How can I convert a `BitmapImage` into a byte array?

The issue relates to the UWP platform, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has the ObservableCollection of images to be serialized to a file?

You could not extract the bitmap from a `BitmapImage`. There is no way to save it to file.

You could use a `WriteableBitmap` instead of a `BitmapImage` and then you can get the pixels data of the `WriteableBitmap`.

```
public static async Task<FileUpdateStatus> SaveToPngImage(this WriteableBitmap bitmap, PickerLocationId location, string fileName) 
{ 
    var savePicker = new FileSavePicker 
    { 
        SuggestedStartLocation = location 
    }; 
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Png Image", new[] { ".png" }); 
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = fileName; 
    StorageFile sFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync(); 
    if (sFile != null) 
    { 
        CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(sFile); 


        using (var fileStream = await sFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)) 
        { 
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream); 
            Stream pixelStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream(); 
            byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length]; 
            await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length); 
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, 
                      (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, 
                      (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 
                      96.0, 
                      96.0, 
                      pixels); 
            await encoder.FlushAsync(); 
        } 


        FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(sFile); 
        return status; 
    } 
    return FileUpdateStatus.Failed; 
}
```

> How can I convert a BitmapImage into a byte array?
>
> There is no way to extract the image data from an ImageSource. You will need to keep track of the original source of the information and recreate the image in the WriteableBitmap from the original source. If you know you are going to need to do this you may be better off just using a WriteableBitmap as your ImageSource to begin with

From Rob’s reply [Convert ImageSource to WriteableBitmap in Metro Windows 8](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c059b1f9-8a28-47c2-a259-3ab561c6e49a/convert-imagesource-to-writeablebitmap-in-metro-windows-8?forum=winappswithcsharp), there is no way to  convert `BitmapImage` to a byte array. If you have used `WriteableBitmap`， It will be easy to do.

```
private byte[] ImageToByeArray(WriteableBitmap wbp)  
{  
   using (Stream stream = wbp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())  
   using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())  
   {  
      stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);  
      return memoryStream.ToArray();  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, that's about what I thought. In the project I will use WriteableBitmap. Thank You!